# Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show some related product in magento theme. 
For that I updated `catalog.xml` file with following code.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</block>
</reference>
```

And added below code in `catalog/product/view.phtml` file.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related'); ?>
```

After this few changes I got this error

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a non-object in magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 815
```

Please suggest what could be the issue of this error.

Comment: on which file this is show the error

Comment: It shows on product detail page

Comment: Please post the full `catalog.xml` `catalog_product_view` section and any snippets from other layout xml files like a custom theme one that might influence this. My guess is *somewhere* the reference is being added to a parent group. Have you tried using another **name** or **as** for the block?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following snippet for the related block xml it appears you are missing some information that this block needs.

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" after="product.info.upsell" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml">
  <action method="setColumnCount">
    <columns>4</columns>
  </action>                    
  <action method="setItemLimit">
    <type>related</type>
    <limit>4</limit>
  </action>
</block>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, But this also not worked..

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related'); ?>
```

in place of

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related'); ?>
```

Comment: I did not agree with your solution because I am using as="related" in xml, so both option will work. There is another issue in my code. Which I am not able to figure out.